# Apllying routing but url is changing but page is not changing

Tags: angular

I am applying routing concept ,ie. when i am clicking on button want to route to another page with same header on the different page ,but when i am routing url is changing but page is not changing

```
//CODE FOR CLICKING BUTTON 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline pull-right" (click)="redirect();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> change</button>

//CODE FOR CALLING FUNCTION
constructor(private router: Router,public zone: NgZone) { }
  redirect(){

    this.router.navigate('/store');
   }

//CODE FOR ROUTER DEFINED
RouterModule.forRoot([

     {path:'',pathMatch: 'full',component:Dashboard1Component},
      {path:'store',component:Store1Component},

    ])
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change how you call the router slightly.

```
this.router.navigate(['/store']);
```

Ensure you have set up router outlet in `app.component.html` (assuming this is where you would want it).

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Some more information can be found with [examples here](https://alligator.io/angular/navigation-routerlink-navigate-navigatebyurl/).

Comment: i have tried this but this is not working,again same problem

Comment: any errors and have you set up <router-outlet></router-outlet>?

Comment: you have any desk id show that i can share my screen?

Comment: "you have any desk id show that i can share my screen? ", No, you can explain the problem here.

Comment: i have tried with applying router-outlet in index.html still facing same issue

Comment: i have tried with applying router-outlet in index.html still facing same issue

Comment: Try adding <router-outlet></router-outlet> in app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the below

`this.router.navigate(['/', 'red-pill']);`

or share the screenshot of the console.

Also refer [this](https://alligator.io/angular/navigation-routerlink-navigate-navigatebyurl/)

Comment: do you have any desk id ?so that i can share my screen

Comment: i also have to use router outlet?

Comment: yes working fine now ,actually there was problem with router outlet ,it was placed in wrong location